# FizzBuzz game involcing C$

Tags: c#, nunit, fizzbuzz

The following error is:

Errors and Failures:
1) Test Failure : fizzbuzz.FizzBuzzTest.TestInputFifteen
     Expected string length 8 but was 4. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "FizzBuzz"
  But was:  "Buzz"
  -----------^

at fizzbuzz.FizzBuzzTest.TestInputFifteen () [0x00000] in :0

2) Test Failure : fizzbuzz.FizzBuzzTest.TestInputOneHundredAndFive
     Expected string length 8 but was 4. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "FizzBuzz"
  But was:  "Buzz"
  -----------^

at fizzbuzz.FizzBuzzTest.TestInputOneHundredAndFive () [0x00000] in :0

Comment: Please put the errors *in the question*. I'd also strong suggest that you learn about data-driven tests - the code is the same in each test, so you could just use `[TestCase(...)]` to make that better.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: I don't see why, to be honest...

Comment: I believe the problem is probably just the lack of `{` after the namespace declaration in the second file. It certainly doesn't feel like it's an error which is really fizzbuzz or nunit-specific.

Comment: Considering the error messages you've posted refers to `FizzBuzz.cs`, and the class here is named `FizzBuzzTest` I think it is highly likely the errors you're seeing is unrelated to the test code but instead related to the code under test. Can you post the contents of `FizzBuzz.cs` (instead) ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I was given a Test and I had to write code to pass the test. The FizzBuzz.cs that you are talking about is the solution contents

Comment: OK, now that you've posted the actual file then the answer here has already been edited to show the actual problem, there is a bracket missing. In future posts, please post the file that is being complained about, even though you may believe the problem to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is that you've omitted `{` after namespace name:

```
  namespace fizzbuzz { // <- this "{"
    public class FizzBuzz {    
      ...
    }
  } // <- and this "}"
```

However even if you amend this typo, you'll face another ones (you can't create an instance of a *static* class, `FizzBuzz` hasn't required constructor etc.); let's *start from a test*, say this one:

```
[Test]
public void TestInputOneHundred() {
    FizzBuzz fizzbuzz = new FizzBuzz(100);
    Assert.AreEqual("Buzz", fizzbuzz.ToString());
}
```

you're creating `FizzBuzz` isntance and then call `ToString()`. So you have to implement something like this:

```
   namespace fizzbuzz { // <- do not forget "{"
      // Not static! You (== your test) want to create instances
      public class FizzBuzz {  
        // create, passing int (exactly as test wants)
        public FizzBuzz(int value) {
          Value = value;
        }

        // ToString will want the value 
        public int Value {get; set;}

        // ToString to call in the test
        public override ToString() {
          if (Value % 5 == 0)  
            return "Buzz";

          return Value.ToString(); 
        }
      }
   }
```

And the test passed. Run another one, e.g.

```
   [Test]
    public void TestInputThree() {
        FizzBuzz fizzbuzz = new FizzBuzz(3);
        Assert.AreEqual("Fizz", fizzbuzz.ToString());
    }
```

To pass this one you have to modify `ToString()` into

```
public override ToString() {
  if (Value % 5 == 0)  
    return "Buzz";
  else if (Value % 3 == 0) // for the 2nd test  
    return "Fizz"; 

  return Value.ToString(); 
}
```

And so on until all the test are passed.

Comment: He's getting compiler errors, the actual question is hidden in a comment.

Comment: @Dan, sorry for typo, it should be `public override String ToString()`, since  `ToString` returns, of course, `String`

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko so I got the last test, but now I am stuck on "FizzBuzz" as an output

Comment: @Dan: well, the condition is pretty clear: *hen divisible by both 3 and 5...*, so all you have to put is `if ((Value % 5 == 0) && (Value % 3 == 0)) return "FizzBuzz";` on the top of `ToString()`

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Yes I did, but I think when the number should appear I messed that up i edited the updated code

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko and its still giving me an error for the return "FizzBuzz"

Comment: @Dan: `if ((Value % 5 == 0) && Value % 3 == 0)) return FizzBuzz`should be *on the top of* `ToString()`, i.e. *first* check for *FizzBuzz* and only then for *Fizz* and *Buzz* separately

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko oh my bad got it

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko one last thing so after doing all the test there is thisYou should consider boundary conditions when you write your code. FizzBuzz is not defined for numbers less than 1.

In this case, you should return the string "Undefined" in any case where the number given is < 1.

Comment: @Dan and boundary conditions should be placed *before* even *FizzBuzz*: since in case of, say, `-100` you want `"Undefined"` not `"FizzBuzz"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko like this if (Value % =< -100)
                                              return "Undefined";

Comment: @Dan: `if (Value < 1) return "Undefined";` - just as you've said: *in any case where the number given is < 1*

Comment: @DmitryBychenko really appreciate your help